# .htaccess rewrite rule for redirection for fixed pattern URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to write .htacces rewrite rules for blog module.

if => www.xyz.com/index.php   It should not redirect anything

if => www.xyz.com/contactus.php   It should not redirect anything

but
if => **www.xyz.com/blogs/test-string1-and-string2**
(URL  pattren fixed for blog pages)

It should redirect to **blog_details.php?id=$1**

I have tried following rules.:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !/blog/

RewriteRule blogs/(\w+)  blog_details.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

This is not perfect rule. It is causing problems while generating sitemaps and Seo results.

I want some strong validation for URL like **.php** at the end of URL or

words separated by hyphen (-) after blog/.  Then I can redirect url.

Comment: But there is no ".php" at the end of the URL you want to redirect (www.xyz.com/blogs/test-string1-and-string2)? Or is this meant to be an inclusive "or"?

Comment: yes, if there is no .php in URL then I want to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

First you need not check the `HTTP_HOST` here, as you are not changing it.

If you do, you should compare it to a possible Hostname, not to a possible URL, i.e.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.nottherightone.tld$
```

To check, if the URL does not end in ".php" *and* contains hyphens, this should be a possbility

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !.php$
RewriteRule blogs/(.*-.*)    blog_details.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: Its working .. but I am creating sitemaps using https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/.. Its giving some fake links like  www.xyz.com/blogs/index.php , www.xyz.com/blogs/contactus.php.. etc.. how to stop it ?

Comment: `.php` is excluded here, so it should not be caused by the rewrite rules here. Or is this another problem?

Answer (score 0):

Following rule should work for you:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blogs/(.+)$ blog_details.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Its working .. but I am creating sitemaps using https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/.. Its giving some fake links like  www.xyz.com/blogs/index.php , www.xyz.com/blogs/contactus.php.. etc.. how to stop it ?

Comment: This rule isn't impacting any other link except `/blogs/something`. `/blogs/contactus.php` will not be impacted due to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` which ignores all real files.